# how to upgrade and migrate postgres dbs to new server machine?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, migration

my production databases run on a centos 5.5 virtual machine. This server has 2 postgres 8.4 clusters installed on 2 different partitions; now my idea is to upgrade both db version and server os (centos 6) in order to set up a newer machine with also much more disk space. In this way i will be covered for many years.
I read postgres documentation and pg_upgrade seems to be a very useful tool but,if i understood well, it can be used only on same machine and on same mounting point. So how can i get my goal? pgdumpall command? note that clusters' sizes are (at the moment) 10gb and 1gb ,but cluster 1 grows up quite fast.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is to simply use `pg_dumpall -f cluster.dump`, then restore with `psql -f cluster.dump` on the new host.

Slightly more sophisticated is to dump globals, then dump each DB separately:

```
pg_dumpall --globals-only > globals.sql
psql -qAt -c 'SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE NOT datistemplate;' -0 |\
  xargs -0 -i pg_dump -Fc -f "{}".pgbackup "{}"
```

Restore with something like:

```
psql -f globals.sql
for f in *.pgbackup; do
  pg_restore -f "$f" -C -d postgres
done
```

In all these cases you may need to run as the `postgres` user.

A 10GB dump is quite reasonable.

If you need to do a low downtime upgrade, there are a few more sophisticated options:

- Set up slony-I or Londiste to replicate changes from the old server to the new one; or
- Install the same version of PostgreSQL on the new server. Set up streaming replication. Fail over to the new server, then `pg_upgrade` to a current PostgreSQL version.

Comment: This answer is much better than mine

Comment: thanks..i'll do some migration simulation to have an evaluation of downtime and to be sure that all works. I'll try also the other methods, also because i'm interested eventually in setting up replication on new machine. luckily we have 2 data centers (one is backup) so i can have exactly the same enviroment to do all the tests i want :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the best thing is to do a full export/import of your database. 10GB is not a big database (relatively) and shouldn't be problematic. Export with pg_dump and import with psql.